# How to configure Gmail to open mailto-links in on-site compose window?

Tags: gmail, chromium, mailto, ubuntu-12.10

I'm trying to make Gmail open a small compose window on the actual site containing the mailto-link, instead of opening a new tab. I don't even know if this is possible. My setup makes searching for answers more difficult than I expected.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with Chromium. To make Gmail my default mail client, I had to install Gnome Gmail. This works just fine except for the mentioned problem. I can't find any conf-file for Gnome Gmail, but I'm surprised if it does not exist.

---

Updated after **user176315**'s help:

Changing

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab(gmailurl)
```

to

```
webbrowser.open_new(gmailurl)
```

in `/usr/bin/gnome-gmail` only resulted in Gmail opening the mailto-link in the same window. Python's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) on `webbrowser.open_new()` says:

> Open url in a new window of the default browser, if possible,
> otherwise, open url in the only browser window.

I also tried

```
webbrowser.open(gmailurl, new=1)
```

but this did the same as `open_new(gmailurl)`

It kinda feels like Chromium is not supported by Python in some way.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME Gmail configuration information is stored in gconf, soon to be dconf. Tab/new window behavior is not a configuration parameter. There is no other configuration file.

You could modify the /usr/bin/gnome-gmail script to open the compose screen as a new window.

Change

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab( gmailurl )
```

to

```
webbrowser.open_new( gmailurl )
```

At the bottom of the script.

Comment: Didn't work, for me: keeps opening gmail page, not the composer...